# Mostrar o resultado de uma query dentro de uma textbox C# Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estou com uma pequena duvida em relação ao mostrar uma query.

No meu website quero mostrar o resultado de uma query.

Por exemplo: 
Nº de funcionarios: [e aqui aparecer o total]

Já tenho as ligações as BD feitas:

```
protected void ligabd2()
{
    adpt1 = new tb_trabalhadorTableAdapter(); 
    tabtrab = new DataSet.tb_trabalhadorDataTable();
    adpt1.Filltrabalhador(tabtrab);
}
```

Comment: Você quer mostrar aonde? De que maneira? Existem muitas possibilidades de interpretação para sua pergunta, tente ser um pouco mais específico

Comment: Mostrar apenas no webform. Peço desculpa como não estou a ver assim muitas formas não fui assim tão preciso .

Comment: E qual é o problema? Já tem algum lugar que você faz a *query*, define os critérios, etc.?

Comment: Por exemplo um textbox 
o query é simples. é mostrar o numero de rows da tabela trabalhador .

Comment: E você não sabe criar um textbox pra apresentar o resultado? Essa é a dúvida?

Comment: Sim é essa a minha duvida